# How to access my-domain/admin in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('/admin', 'Backend\HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
```

is from `routes/web.php` and it's not working online. It's fine in local

```
Route::get('/superadmin', 'Backend\HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
```

or any name except '`admin`' is working online and local.
But I've already used `/admin` in my project in many places.
That's why I can't use `/superadmin`.

Please Help.

website backend:
`http://ischebazar.com/admin`
login:
`http://ischebazar.com/admin/login` is working.

Comment: Just a hunch. Maybe your host already took the /admin url. Check routes of your application, check the hosting admin panel, htaccess. Etc

Comment: @LeoNogueira Thanks, But Other projects are working fine in same cpanel :'(

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I need to post an answer for this.

What do you mean by it does not work? Does it show you the laravel 404 page, a server error or a blank page?

If it shows you the laravel 404 page try clearing the route cache: `php artisan route:clear`.

If it's a blank page, try checking if you have a folder called `admin` in the document root of the project.

For a server error I can't guess whats wrong but you can provide additional information if this is the case.

Comment: It shows a blank page. And also dont have any folder :(

Comment: @BlaBla are you sure you don't have any folder named `admin` ? This is the typical issue in this case. Also, what type of status code do you receive when you acess /admin ?

Comment: @BlaBla apparently you do have a folder called `admin` inside `public`. For laravel websites, the `public` folder is the document root. Tthat's why it's not working for you. Rename the folder to something else, update the code to reflect that change and you can use the `/admin` route.

Comment: No @Razvan bro. I don't have any.

Comment: This is from your site. http://ischebazar.com/public/admin/css/main.css . It loads css files from an `admin` folder.

Comment: This CSS is in `admin` folder and which is contained in `public` folder.

Comment: That's the issue you have, the document root of a laravel project is inside the `public` folder. When you access `yoursite.com/admin` first it looks for a folder inside your `public` one. If it does not find anything, it redirects the request to `index.php` and the routes file takes over. To fix this there are two solutions: rename your `admin` folder from the `public` or you can change the url to point to something else besides `admin`.

Comment: Hai, @Razvan. Thanks, you'r right. I've figured it out. But, how to change?

Comment: You have to rename either the `public/admin` folder or change the route name. You can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command to clear out cache,

`php artisan config:cache`